# Notation of a function in coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

I have a question about some notation which puzzles me a lot. Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$. Then people often write or say that if we choose coordinates $x=(x^1,…,x^n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $u=(u^1,…,u^m)$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ we can think of $f$ as a collection of $m$ functions as follows:
$$u^1=u^1(x^1,…,x^n),…,u^m=u^m(x^1,…,x^n).$$

My question is about the last line above. I'm sure it is just a matter of notation, but anyhow I want to grasp the logic behind this kind of notation since it appears frequently and it is not very convenient if one has to think about the notation more often than should be needed. Would someone be so kind to explain it to me?

Just to give you a taste of the questions which I have in mind:

First of all, it the functions $u^i$ are by definition coordinates (e.g. cartesian coordinates, polar coordinates etc.) which should be independent of any function $f$. At the same time it is said, that they represent the function $f$ whereas the function $f$ does not even appear in the last line above! Furthermore it looks to me as if the coordinates $(x^1,…,x^n)$ are plugged in into the functions $u^i$. But if the functions $u^i$ are coordinates of $\mathbb{R}^m$ they should depend on $m$, though not on $n$ arguments.

Any help will be very appreciated. Best wishes

Comment: The function $f$ is simply
$$f(x^1, \dots, x^n) = (u^1(x^1, \dots, x^n),\dots,u^m(x^1, \dots, x^n))$$ Why do you say that the $u^i$ are independent of $f$? they are exactly the components of $f$. i.e. compositions $\pi_i \circ f$, where $\pi_i$ is the projection on the $i$-th coordinate.

Comment: Yes I understand what is meant. But it should be more precisely written as $(u^1(f(x^1,…,x^n)),…,u^m(f(x^1,…,x^n)))$. So the f is omitted in the notation. Is it always meant this way? Are there rules when to omit the function $f$ and when not?

Comment: The functions $u_i$ are not the projections! They are the coordinate functions of $f$! If one denotes by $\pi_i$ the function $(t^1, \dots, t^m) \mapsto t^i$, then $u^i = \pi_i \circ f$. This means that
$u_i(x^1, \dots, x^n) = i$-th component of $f(x^1, \dots, x^n)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the beginning there just were ${\mathbb R}^n$ with coordinates $(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ and ${\mathbb R}^m$ with coordinates $(u_1,\ldots, u_m)$. The $x_k$ as well as the $u_i$ were independent real variables encoding the position of  points ${\bf x}\in{\mathbb R}^n$, resp. ${\bf u}\in{\mathbb R}^m$ living freely in the wild.

Then came a mathematician considering a certain map ${\bf f}:\>{\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}^m$ defined in so many words: by a geometric construction, as time-one-map of a dynamic system, what have you. This map moves individual points ${\bf x}\in{\mathbb R}^n$ to points ${\bf u}:={\bf f}({\bf x})\in{\mathbb R}^m$. In order to do computations with this ${\bf f}$ we (sometimes) have to use its expression in terms of coordinates. In this way ${\bf f}$ appears as a tuple map
$${\bf f}:\quad(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto\left\{\eqalign{u_1&:=f_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\cr
&\vdots\cr
u_m&:=f_m(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\cr}\right.\ .$$
It is at this point that a handy abuse of notation is very common: In certain cases we are not so much interested in the map ${\bf f}$ per se, but in the *object produced by* ${\bf f}$ in ${\bf u}$-space: a curve $\gamma$, or a surface $S$. Therefore we just write $u_i$ for $f_i({\bf x})$ and then $\dot{\bf u}$ when we mean the tangent vector of $\gamma$, etc. *This is only allowed if only one ${\bf f}$ is at stake*. If we want, e.g., to argue about the angle of intersection between two different curves we have to return to the full notation involving ${\bf f}$.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at this as follows: let $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be some function and $u^i:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the $i$-th coordinate function (i.e. for $y=(y^1, \ldots , y^m)^t$ you have $u^i(y) = y^i$). Note this is nothing but a real valued function on $\mathbb{R}^m $.

Then what you denote as $u^i(x)$ is simply $u^i\circ f(x)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Thomas. I understand what you mean. But isn't there some abuse of notation then? The functions $u^i$ denote on the one hand the coordinate functions of $f$, i.e. $u^i=(u^i\circ f)$. On the other hand they are coordinates for the euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^m$

Comment: @asd If you just write $u^i(x)$ in this example then this is a shortcut which you may, in fact, consider as an abuse of notation. But esp in differential geometry you will often look at multiple compositions, so quite often you will easier be able to grasp the meaning when a notation with a little abuse in it is used. If you write down something like this you should always check whether you still know how to write it down in a precise and correct manner (though this may become very cumbersome).

Answer (score 1):

$f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ implies that $f:x=(x^1,\ldots,x^n)\mapsto f(x)=u=(u^1,\ldots,u^m)$. For each $x$, $f(x)$ inhabits $m$-dimensional space, so by definition it has $m$ coordinates; these are represented by $u^1,\ldots,u^m$. They could as easily be called $f^1(x),\ldots,f^m(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

I think that an example is necessary. Let $f : \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^3$ be defined as
$$f(x,y) = (x+y, y^7, \cos(x+2y)-4)$$
then $f$ is represented in coordinates by the three functions $u^1, u^2, u^3: \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$
$$u^1(x,y)= x+y$$ $$u^2(x,y)= y^7$$ $$u^3(x,y)= \cos(x+2y)-4$$

Comment: This is a nice example. Thank you for that. I think my problem is that, the functions $u^i$ were introduced as coordinates (see my initial question) before there was any function $f$ to talk about. But then they depend on the function $f$, i.e. they are the $i-$th coordinate representation of $f$. Why is this so natural for you, but not for me?

Comment: This is just a taste of notation. Actually, I personally find it confusing, since in this setting you can define only one function. But this is how many people write things (physicists in particular)...